# How to get a spring-framework-3.0.5-RELEASE-with-dependencies.zip file for Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, dependencies, spring-3

I have a bit of an issue with Spring 3 and it involves its dependencies or better said "their lack of...".

When you [download](http://www.springsource.com/download/community) Spring 2.5.x for example you get a `spring-framework-2.5.6-with-dependencies.zip` file containing the Spring distribution as well as its dependencies.

For Spring 3 there isn't one. You only get the distro while dependencies are managed in Maven repository and retrieved with Ivy. That was the decision springsource fellows took. Which brings me to my problem.

At work Maven repository has "forbidden access" written all over it and we don't use Ivy. We use Maven but with a local enterprise repository and nothing beyond that is allowed (security concerns yada yada which ultimately makes sense but makes my job as a developer harder). To put something in the local repository means approvals, deployments of resources, configurations, acces rights, time, money etc.

It is OK with a few JARS here and there but I imagine Spring dependencies mean more than a few JARs. So that will be approved and installed over o long period of time. Meanwhile we can't develop in Spring 3 (while everything is set up in the local repository) so we need the dependencies.

I found this page here:

http://static.springsource.org/downloads/nightly/snapshot-download.php?project=SPR

which contains some dependencies but i need it for release 3.0.5 not for nightly builds.

**In short, I need a `spring-framework-3.0.5-RELEASE-with-dependencies.zip` file. Ho do I get one?**

P.S. I must mention that I can't just download something home and bring everything on a stick which is the first suggestion that pops in mind. Other rules apply for this :D, so I need an official release to download.

Comment: Check this out this [Wiki page on GitHub](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/wiki/Building-a-distribution-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main reasons that there isn't a big “Spring 3 with everything” build is that you probably don't need it. (It's absolutely huge!) Instead, you're supposed to identify the parts that you actually need and only include them. The problem is that this makes it hard for you.

Alas, the best way I see long-term for you is to get Spring 3 and its dependencies into your institutional Maven repository (switching to Ivy wouldn't really help; the institutional problem is not with Maven but with depending on unvetted external libraries). Yes, it's awkward but that's what you've got to work with. Sneaking things in the back-door won't help! Perhaps it would be reasonable to inquire whether there is a relatively rapid method to get things approved where previous versions have been found acceptable (which might be “yes, subject to there being no license surprises”)?

You'll probably need to use Maven (or Ivy, but I don't know it) to get the full list of dependencies first, so that you can describe exactly what changes are actually involved, and be aware that some of the dependencies might already be approved.

(I just wish I had a better idea for how to deal with your process, but working against both its spirit and letter is a way to get a corporate bureaucrat very upset. Life's not worth such things.)

Answer (score 6):

Steps:

1. Go to http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE.zip
2. When you hit the URL, your download for jar files starts automatically
3. After unzipping, there is a folder called `dist` which contains the following jar files for spring 3.0.5

   - org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

**NOTE** : You can download any release of spring framwork just by modifying the release version to **3.0.1** or **3.2.5**(any other versions according to your need)in the above mentioned URL

Answer (score 3):

I've shared the very origin file from Spring official site:
http://kuai.xunlei.com/d/QBEMGYUXOOKN
http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE-dependencies.zip

Answer (score 0):

Create a project at home, add what you need in spring 3 to that, open the project with eclipse+m2eclipse and view the dependency hierarchy. That will then tell you what you need as dependencies on spring.

Chances are a lot of the dependencies are the same as they were in spring 2.5 as a lot of the spring 3 stuff didn't change.

You can ask your maven at home to download all the dependencies... and you'll have your own version of spring+dependencies